# How to extract percentages from counter function

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter, percentage

I got this function and from the counter, I wanted to extract the numbers of each element in the list and to convert it into percentages so I can know the percentage of each element in the list.

```py
from collections import Counter
import random

dice_rolls = []
for i in range(0, dice_amount):
    dice_rolls.append(random.randint(1,dice_face))
num = Counter(dice_rolls)
```

Comment: `total = sum(num.values(); percentages = {roll: count * 100.0 / total for roll, count in num.items()}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - get the total count with `sum` over the counter's values (though you could just use `len(dice_rolls)` or `dice_amount` for that, of course), and then print things out.

The `Counter` is a dict at heart, so you could just use `.items()`, but you can also use `.most_common()`, which yields pairs in decreasing count order.

```
import collections
import random

dice_rolls = []
dice_amount = 42
dice_face = 6
for i in range(dice_amount):
    dice_rolls.append(random.randint(1, dice_face))
num = collections.Counter(dice_rolls)

total = sum(num.values())
for face, count in num.most_common():
    print(f"{face}: {count} ({count/total:.2%})")
```

prints out eg

```
6: 8 (19.05%)
3: 8 (19.05%)
2: 7 (16.67%)
1: 7 (16.67%)
4: 6 (14.29%)
5: 6 (14.29%)
```